# iPad OpenGL ES FPS too slow!

Tags: ipad, opengl-es

I'm currently working on an OpenGL ES 1.1 app for the iPad

its running at full 768x1024 iPad resolution, with textures, polygons, and the works

but **only at about 30 fps!** (not fast enough for my purposes)

im pretty sure its not my code, because when i lowered the resolution, the FPS increased, eventually the normal 60 at iPod touch resoultion

Is anyone else encountering this FPS slowdown?
should I reduce the size then scale up?... also, would upgrading to opengl 2.0 increase speed?

any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: So when you reduced the resolution to iPod touch resolution you got the same performance as the iPod touch, but you're distressed that when you greatly increased the resolution, the code was slower?

More resolution = more work. Some code snippets will probably be necessary for anyone to give any meaningful guidance.

Comment: True, there's more work, but the iPad has the A4 processor that can easily render that many pixels at 60fps.  I think it's just my computer that is lagging, it will probably work fine on the real thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iPad has the exact same GPU as the iPhone 3GS, so you would probably expect worse fullscreen performance on the iPad due to having to push 5 times as many pixels.

If this is the case, then using scaling is probably the best solution. After all, even console developers have to do it!

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem when porting an iPhone game to iPad. There are few optimizations that raised FPS from 5-6 to 20+:

- using vbo-s
- reducing as much as possible per fragment operations(fog, blend, multi-texturing)
- putting some operations on CPU(lights for example)
- using multi-texturing instead of multi-pass with blend
- improving culling algorithm(now we have a better CPU)